# when including victory chart react-native slider becomes laggy and state value change is reflecting lately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, victory-charts, react-native-elements

The problem is that when I just use a slider only with no Victory chart in the application only just implementing the slider then there is no problem in the slider. But when I use the slider along with the victort chart then the slider is laggy and the state value change is reflecting on screen very late.

To see full details with screenshot/GIF [click here](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/issues/1924)

Answer (score 1):

this is due to the fact that you are sending values to the state as dragging with `onChange`, and **this will cause a re-render every time**.

If you render **few things nothing happens**, but **when the render is more heavy** this get more noticeable.

This can be fixed in 2 way:

- Manage update in child components implementing
  `componentShouldUpdate()` lifecycle callback
- Simply update the state in `onSlidingComplete` props instead of `onChange` prop

Comment: but if I update the  state in `onSlidingComplete` then I can't show the change in state value on screen in real time, as I  have  to show  the state value on the screen so that user can see what is the value when user slides the slider so that he can instant decided when to stop the sliding.

Comment: and also can u elaborate the  first method how should I do it as I am new so does not know  how to do it.

Comment: Hi mate, read https://blog.bitsrc.io/react-16-lifecycle-methods-how-and-when-to-use-them-f4ad31fb2282?gi=c2ed69d9c082 and react docs about it

Comment: I tried that but the problem is that I have to show the state value on the screen in real time as the slider is sliding, can any method to this such that there is no lagging issue

Comment: and also since after the change in value of slider the chart is also based on that slider value so if I render few thing then my chart will not re render, but I have to re render both as the chart will be drawn on the basis of that slider value. Hence both things need to be re render at same time